VB.net code call excel 2019 by interop create the 00374 fault
I have an vb.net service which use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to call excel to generate a report which will read an .xls file and generate an excel file. However when it try to use excel, it have the following error.
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.10414.20002, time stamp: 0x66c2e79b
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.14393.7330, time stamp: 0x66bad250
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f7103
Faulting process id: 0xf6c
Faulting application start time: 0x01db2391ece1bbeb
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: db8a60db-920c-4ba6-8557-aa2d9c052d7f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

So find in the internet, there seems to memory heap corruption. And here is my code.
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class ExcelXlsxGeneratorEngine
    Implements ReportingServiceAgentLib.IGeneratorEngine

Private existingList As New ArrayList
    Private theNewProcess As Process
    Private cacheSheetName As String = ""
    Private _filename As String
    Private _destFolder As String
    Private _fileNameAsPrefix As Boolean = True

Private wb As Object
    Private wbs As Object
    Private xl As Object

Private _lastError As String = ""

Public Function PostProcessing() As String Implements ReportingServiceAgentLib.IGeneratorEngine.PostProcessing
        Try
            If cacheSheetName <> "" Then
                xl.DisplayAlerts = False
                wb. Sheets(cacheSheetName). Delete()
                xl.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If

wb.save()

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb)
            wb = Nothing

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbs)
            wbs = Nothing

xl.Quit()
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xl)
            xl = Nothing

GC. Collect()
            GC. WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        Catch ex As Exception
            _lastError = ex. ToString
        Finally
            If Not theNewProcess Is Nothing Then
                Try
                    theNewProcess.Kill()

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
            End If
        End Try
        Return Me._filename
    End Function

Public Sub PreProcessing(ByVal filename As String) Implements ReportingServiceAgentLib.IGeneratorEngine.PreProcessing
        Try
            Try
                Dim procList() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
                For i As Integer = 0 To procList.Length - 1
                    existingList.Add(procList(i). Id)
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception

End Try

'commented to use the new Office Excel Interop to work with office 2019
            'xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            xl = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()

' loop to get the new process
            Try
                Dim procList() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
                For i As Integer = 0 To procList.Length - 1
                    Dim id As Integer = procList(i). Id
                    If Not existingList.Contains(id) Then
                        theNewProcess = procList(i)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception

End Try

' open template
            wbs = xl.Workbooks
            wb = wbs. Open(filename) ', False, 5, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, False, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, True, False, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, False, False, False)
            ' save to temp folder in XLSX first
            Dim newFilePath As String = ""
            If Me._fileNameAsPrefix Then
                newFilePath = IO. Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) & "-" & Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".xlsx"
            Else
                newFilePath = Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".xlsx"
            End If
            newFilePath = IO. Path.Combine(_destFolder, newFilePath) ' _filename. Replace(".xls", "-" & Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".xls")
            'wb. SaveAs(newFilePath, FileFormat:=51)
            While (True)
                Try
                    wb. SaveAs(newFilePath, 51, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 3, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
                    Exit While
                Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
                    If ((ex. ErrorCode And &HFFFF) = &H10A) Then
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                    Else
                        Throw ex
                    End If
                End Try
            End While

wb. Close()
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb)

' re-open since the template may not a XLSX file
            wb = wbs. Open(newFilePath)

Me._filename = newFilePath

cacheSheetName = ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Dim st As New StackTrace(True)
            'st = New StackTrace(ex, True)
            'EventLog.WriteEntry("", "Line happened the exeption: " & st. GetFrame(0). GetFileLineNumber(). ToString, EventLogEntryType.Error)

'_lastError = ex. ToString
            Dim st As New StackTrace(ex, True)
            Dim frame As StackFrame = st. GetFrame(0)
            Dim lineNumber As Integer = frame. GetFileLineNumber()

EventLog.WriteEntry("", "Exception at line: " & lineNumber & ", Message: " & ex. Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

Public Sub ProcessNonQuery(ByVal target As String, ByRef para As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of ReportingServiceAgentLib.ReportParameter)) Implements ReportingServiceAgentLib.IGeneratorEngine.ProcessNonQuery
        Try
            Dim buf() As String = target. Split(":")
            Dim xlSheet As Object = Nothing

While (True)
                Try
                    xlSheet = wb. Sheets(buf(0))
                    Exit While
                Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
                    If ((ex. ErrorCode And &HFFFF) = &H10A) Then
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                    Else
                        Throw ex
                    End If
                End Try
            End While

If (xlSheet Is Nothing) Then Throw New Exception("Unable to load Excel Sheet")

Dim startCell As Object = xlSheet.Range(buf(1) & ":" & buf(1))
            Dim startCol As Integer = startCell.Column
            Dim startRow As Integer = startCell.Row

Dim val As String = startCell.Value2
            For Each rp As ReportingServiceAgentLib.ReportParameter In para
                If rp. Value = "%" Then
                    val = val. Replace("{" & rp. Name & "}", "All")
                Else
                    If (rp. Type.ToLower() = "date") Then
                        val = val. Replace("{" & rp. Name & "}", Date.Parse(rp. Value). ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
                    Else
                        val = val. Replace("{" & rp. Name & "}", rp. Value)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            startCell.Value2 = val

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(startCell)
            startCell = Nothing
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet)
            xlSheet = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            _lastError = ex. ToString
        End Try
    End Sub

Public Function GetLastError() As String Implements ReportingServiceAgentLib.IGeneratorEngine.GetLastError
        Return _lastError
    End Function

Public Sub ProcessQuery(ByVal target As String, ByVal row As Integer, ByVal col As Integer, ByRef header() As String, ByRef data(,) As Object, ByRef para As List(Of ReportingServiceAgentLib.ReportParameter)) Implements ReportingServiceAgentLib.IGeneratorEngine.ProcessQuery
        Try
            Dim buf() As String = target. Split(":")
            Dim xlSheet As Object = Nothing

While (True)
                Try
                    xlSheet = wb. Sheets(buf(0))
                    Exit While
                Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
                    If ((ex. ErrorCode And &HFFFF) = &H10A) Then
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                    Else
                        Throw ex
                    End If
                End Try
            End While

If (xlSheet Is Nothing) Then Throw New Exception("Unable to load Excel Sheet")

Dim startCell As Object = xlSheet.Range(buf(1) & ":" & buf(1))
            Dim startCol As Integer = startCell.Column
            Dim startRow As Integer = startCell.Row

If row > 0 Then
                ' create a new worksheet for cache
                Dim cSheet As Object
                If cacheSheetName = "" Then
                    cSheet = wb. Sheets.Add(After:=xlSheet)
                    cacheSheetName = cSheet.Name
                Else
                    cSheet = wb. Sheets(cacheSheetName)
                End If

Dim cr As Object = cSheet.Range("A1")
                Dim cr2 As Object = cr. Resize(row, col)

' copy the format to the cache range
                Dim r2 As Object = xlSheet.Cells(startRow, startCol + col - 1)
                Dim r As Object = xlSheet.Range(startCell, r2)

r.Copy()

cr2. PasteSpecial(-4122, -4142, False, False)
                cr2. Value = data
                cr2. Cut()

' insert the cache to the target
                Dim r3 As Object = xlSheet.Cells(startRow + 1, startCol)
                r3. Insert(-4121)

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(r)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(r2)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(r3)
                r = Nothing
                r2 = Nothing
                r3 = Nothing

xlSheet.Select()

' remove cache
                cr2. Delete()
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cr2)
                cr2 = Nothing

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cr)
                cr = Nothing

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cSheet)
                cSheet = Nothing
            End If

Dim c As Object = xlSheet.Cells(startRow + row + 1, startCol)
            c.EntireRow.Delete()
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(c)
            c = Nothing

c = xlSheet.Cells(startRow, startCol)
            c.EntireRow.Delete()
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(c)
            c = Nothing

' hide any raw data sheet
            If (buf(0). ToLower(). Contains("raw")) Then
                xlSheet.Visible = False
            End If

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(startCell)
            startCell = Nothing
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet)
            xlSheet = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            _lastError = ex. ToString
        End Try
    End Sub

Public Sub SetDestinationFolder(ByVal folderPath As String) Implements ReportingServiceAgentLib.IGeneratorEngine.SetDestinationFolder
        _destFolder = folderPath
    End Sub

Public Property FileNameAsPrefix() As Boolean Implements ReportingServiceAgentLib.IGeneratorEngine.FileNameAsPrefix
        Get
            Return _fileNameAsPrefix
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _fileNameAsPrefix = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

May I know is that caused by my code? And what should I fix it by code or the excel issue?

Which the service exe to calling the v15 interop excel. And the error happened.

There's way too much code there, indicating that you haven't really investigated sufficiently. Please read this and edit your question accordingly. In your case, the important word is "minimal". There's no way you need all that code to demonstrate the issue. If you make the effort to strip out all that isn't relevant, you might even be able to identify the issue yourself. Note that, if you have to create a new project to test specific functionality then that's what you do. That's part of development.
